# Combining and inverting multiple files with missing data in R

Tags: r

I have multiple files with tab separated data that looks like this:

```
A 25
B 50
C 10
D 30
```

What I would like is to invert and combine them. So it looks like this:

```
filename A B C D
file1 25 50 10 30
file2 20 15 0 10
file3 60 20 30 0
```

As you can see there are some files that have missing data (file2 lacks a value for C so there is no row C in that file). I would like to have any missing columns reported as 0.

I tried using data = lapply(filelist, read.table, sep = "\t") but this just gives me:

```
data
[[1]]
         V1      V2
1         C   27660
2         B       4
3         E   40128
4         D    4584
5         G   43078

[[2]]
         V1      V2
1         C   31530
2         E   47978
3         D    5268
4         G   54636
```

Which is not what I want. I want the letters to be the columns and the rows to be the file names.

Comment: If the files don't all have the same number of columns, how is your example file sufficient information for us to use to craft a solution? Wouldn't it make sense to provide an example that actually represents your files?

Comment: Read your files and then use `merge`

Comment: can merge be used with more than 2 files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use the `plyr` package's `rbind.fill()` function. Basically you would read in your files, transpose them with `t()`, and then use rbind.fill to join them all up into one big data frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the file name in a new column of the data.frames,
concatenate them, and reshape the result.

```
# Not run:
# data <- lapply(filelist, read.table, sep = "\t") 
# names(d) <- filelist

# Use sample data instead
d <- list(
  file1 = data.frame( V1 = sample(LETTERS, 10), V2 = rpois(10,10) ),
  file2 = data.frame( V1 = sample(LETTERS, 10), V2 = rpois(10,10) ),
  file3 = data.frame( V1 = sample(LETTERS, 10), V2 = rpois(10,10) )
)

# Add the file name as a column
for(i in names(d)) {
  d[[i]] <- data.frame( file=i, d[[i]] )
}

# Concatenate everything
d <- do.call(rbind, d)

# Convert to wide format
library(reshape2)
dcast(d, file ~ V1, fill=0 )
```